# Conditionally populating ComboBox based on selected value from another ComboBox

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, userform

I have a Sheet called *TestTable* which contains a named table called *TeamNameTable* that contains data like below. I need this data to be editable as people are added/removed so it can easily be edited without having to mess around in VBA.

`+------------+------------+ | TeamNumber | MemberName | +------------+------------+ | Team1      | Aaron      | | Team1      | Bob        | | Team1      | Charles    | | Team2      | Dave       | | Team2      | Eddie      | | Team2      | Frank      | +------------+------------+`

I have a UserForm called *UserForm1* that has two ComboBoxes (*cbxTeam* and *cbxName*). cbxTeam is prepopulated with these team names: Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4.

My goal is to be able to select one of the four teams from cbxTeam then, based on that value, populate cbxName with only the MemberNames from TestTable that are part of Team1, etc. I'm not sure that using a Dictionary is appropriate for this nor my use of arrays within the Dictionary. Totally open to suggestions on the appropriate collection type.

So, selecting Team1 in cbxTeam would populate cbxName with Aaron, Bob, Charles. Selecting Team2 would populate cbxName with Dave, Eddie, Frank...

I've tried using a Dictionary using keys (Team1, Team2) with arrays as the value (team1Array, team2Array).

The two arrays within the Dictionary are populated with the below, but I actually need the range to be dynamic in case another person gets added to Team1, Team2, etc. I'm stumped on how to do that. cbxName *is* being populated but only because I've explicitly defined a static range. I'm not leveraging the benefit of the named table.

```
Dim team1Array As Variant
team1Array = Range("B2:B4")

Dim team2Array As Variant
team2Array = Range("B5:B7")
```

The whole thing is being trigged on the cbxTeam_Change() event:

```
Public Sub cbxTeam_Change()

Dim team1Array As Variant
team1Array = Range("B2:B4") 'Not sure how to use the named table TeamNameTable. Needs to be dynamic

Dim team2Array As Variant
team2Array = Range("B5:B7") 'Not sure how to use the named table TeamNameTable. Needs to be dynamic

Dim teamMembership
Set teamMembership = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

teamMembership.Add "Team1", team1Array
teamMembership.Add "Team2", team2Array

If teamMembership.Exists("Team1") Then
    cbxName.List = team1Array
End If
End Sub
```

This is my first post so hopefully I've expressed my goal succinctly and shown what I've tried. If I'm missing any info that would help you help me, please let me know. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each row in TeamNameTable, and then for each team that matches the team selected from cbxTeam, add it to your dictionary as a key value.  Then assign the keys to the List property of cbxName.  Try the following...

```
Private Sub cbxTeam_Change()

    Me.cbxName.Clear

    If cbxTeam.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub 'entry doesn't match list

    Dim selectedTeam As String
    selectedTeam = Me.cbxTeam.Value

    Dim teamMembership As Object
    Set teamMembership = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    With Range("TeamNameTable")
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If UCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = UCase(selectedTeam) Then
                teamMembership(.Cells(i, 2)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If teamMembership.Count > 0 Then
        Me.cbxName.List = Application.Transpose(teamMembership.keys())
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that if TeamNameTable includes the header row, you can exclude it when looping by replacing...

```
For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
```

with

```
For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
```

Comment: Domenic, that's amazing. Thank you so much for helping me tick all the boxes of what I was aiming for.

Tested adding another row to TeamNameTable and the additional user populated in cbxName when the corresponding Team # was selected.

I think I understand what's going on in your solution but will have to examine it more closely to get a thorough understanding of it.

Thanks again!